# cordova-plugin-crypt-file - requireCordovaModule error

Tags: cordova, module, require

I just upgrade Cordova to version 9. It cased plugin cordova-plugin-crypt-file to stop working - when I build the application, I get error

```
Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "path" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
```

It looks like the issue is with file hooks/after_prepare.js. The code is

```
var path              = context.requireCordovaModule('path'),
        fs                = context.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
        crypto            = context.requireCordovaModule('crypto'),
        Q                 = context.requireCordovaModule('q'),
        cordova_util      = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-lib/src/cordova/util'),
        platforms         = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms'),
        Parser            = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/parser'),
        ParserHelper      = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/parserhelper/ParserHelper'),
        ConfigParser      = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-common').ConfigParser;
```

So I changed all context.requireCordovaModule to simple require. It produces new error message:

```
Cannot find module 'cordova-lib/src/cordova/util'
```

Please, could anybody help me with fix? Or, is there any alternative plugin?

Comment: Sry, not yet. I have to finish the project at first. I don't want to risk my deadlines by experimenting with the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use the following plugin:

https://github.com/PeterHdd/cordova-plugin-crypto-file

It is based on the `cordova-plugin-crypt-file`.

The above plugin was made to work with `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`, I have updated the plugin and now it works with cordova 9, so there is no need to downgrade.

To install it do the following:

```
npm i cordova-plugin-crypto-file@latest
```

latest version 1.4.0 fixes the cordova 9 issue.

Comment: It's been working for a while.. Are u not getting that the file are encrypted before build finishes? The files get encrypted before build and decrypted when running.

Comment: I just tested it again https://imgur.com/a/71SFcEe it is working as normal. Please tell me what you are trying to do if you are having any issue. @MD.Riyaz

Comment: @MD.Riyaz what was the problem?

Comment: @Peter_Haddad Yep.

Comment: @MD.Riyaz yes, but what was it?

Comment: I don't know, but plugin removes than install again its work fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. You need to downgrade cordova to the version 8.1.2

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm cache clean --force
npm i -g cordova@8.1.2
```

Comment: Yep, it was my solution as well, but once we have to upgrade Cordova and as the plugin is not maintained, we have to fix it our self.

Answer (score 1):

This fix works for me on Cordova 9.0, cordova-ios:

In file:

> cordova-plugin-crypt-file/hooks/after_prepare.js

, replace:

```
var path              = context.requireCordovaModule('path'),
    fs                = context.requireCordovaModule('fs'),
    crypto            = context.requireCordovaModule('crypto'),
    Q                 = context.requireCordovaModule('q'),
    cordova_util      = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-lib/src/cordova/util'),
    platforms         = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms'),
    Parser            = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/parser'),
    ParserHelper      = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/parserhelper/ParserHelper'),
    ConfigParser      = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-common').ConfigParser;
```

with:

```
var path              = require('path'),
    fs                = require('fs'),
    crypto            = require('crypto'),
    Q                 = require('q'),
    cordova_util      = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-lib/src/cordova/util'),
    platforms         = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms'),
    ConfigParser      = context.requireCordovaModule('cordova-common').ConfigParser;
```

Then remove the generated "ios" platform folder and re-add the "ios" platform again.