# The latest version of the plugin is not installed

Tags: cordova, plugins

I'm using cordova 9.0.0.  I'm trying to download the latest version of cordova-plugin-crypto-file plugin. But for some reason the installed version 1.2.1. What could be the reason?

I tried to install the plugin in several ways:

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crypto-file

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crypto-file@latest

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crypto-file@1.4.0

After installing the latest version of the plugin in the ways described above, the previous version 1.2.1 was installed

Comment: where does it say that you have v1.4.0? the github repo master version is  version="1.2.1"

Comment: @NidhinJoseph [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55326722/cordova-plugin-crypt-file-requirecordovamodule-error) answer that there is a version 1.4.0 compatible with the version of Cordova 9.0.0

Comment: but, check the [plugin.xml](https://github.com/PeterHdd/cordova-plugin-crypto-file/blob/master/plugin.xml) file which actually says the version is 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You are using the latest version of [cordova-plugin-crypto-file](https://github.com/PeterHdd/cordova-plugin-crypto-file) which is `v1.2.1`. It happens that the [plugin.xml](https://github.com/PeterHdd/cordova-plugin-crypto-file/blob/master/plugin.xml) version is `v1.2.1` whereas the [package.json](https://github.com/PeterHdd/cordova-plugin-crypto-file/blob/master/package.json) is `v1.4.0`, meaning the `plugin.xml` was not updated. You can check your local `package.json` file to confirm if you are using the latest and the greatest.

And yes, this version has been updated to work with Cordova 9.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, in my package.json file version 1.4.0. But my app still crashes when I specify the encryption subjects by editing plugin.xml.

Comment: @ОлесяЕгорова I think the crash issue should be raised as a different post . Please feel free to accept the answer to help others solve similar issue, thanks.